# C++ XAML use control as function argument

Tags: c++, xaml, c++-cx

To simplify adding text to `UI::XAML::TextBlock` I wrote a function:

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();
private:
    void add_to_console(TextBlock^ text_block, String^ str)
    {
        text_block->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler(
            [text_block, str]()
        {
            text_block->Text += str;
        }));
    }
};
```

but, it generates a lot of errors:

`c2061 - syntax error - identifier TextBlock,`

`c2065 - undeclared identifier text_block.`

How could I write this function to be able use any TextBlock?

Comment: You don't have an active `using namespace` directive in your .h file.  So spell it out, it is Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock

Comment: @HansPassant Strange, but if i dont write "using namespace" or as i write in my answer directly, and write just TextBlock^, intellisense says it right and this object is exactly Windows::UI..TextBlock^

Comment: Because of how intellisense is implemented, types will be found by it even though the declaration cannot strictly be found by the compiler. Particularly in class definitions and in .h files.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like in argument list i need place an Platform::Object^ obj, then

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock^ text_block = reinterpret_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock^>(obj);
```

and there use it as i wish

Comment: You don't, you just need the using namespace as Hans said in his comment several months ago.